# How to pass extra data along with the Intent obtained from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent()?

Tags: android, google-signin

I need to pass a text-string along with the Google Sign-In Intent, so that I can retrieve it later in the `onActivityResult` method.

I trigger the GSI account chooser activity with the following code

```
GoogleSignInOptions googleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestIdToken("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
        .requestEmail()
        .build();
final GoogleSignInClient client = GoogleSignIn.getClient(MainActivity.activity, googleSignInOptions);
Intent signInIntent = client.getSignInIntent();

// As extra
signInIntent.putExtra("CALLSTACK_UID", newCallStack.uid);

this.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
```

and try to retrieve it later via

```
@Override protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        String callstack_uid = data.getStringExtra("CALLSTACK_UID");
        //...
    }
}
```

`data.getStringExtra("CALLSTACK_UID")` is always returning `null`, even when it should be returning a String.

Is my only option here to create a static variable in the activity instead of passing the value through the intent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First `intent` is passed to `startActivityForResult`.
2. Second `intent` is passed from google sign in as a parameter to `onActivityResult`.

Google activity with sign in creates the `new Intent` and returns it to your app.

So there is two intents and they will never be the same object, so you can not expect data from the first `intent` to be in the second `intent`;

Just save the value in the field of the `activity` and also add it to `onSaveInstanceState`.

P.S static fields not always are a good choice (e.g. can cause memory leaks)